# react shards history.push only appends to url, will not redirect

Tags: reactjs, web-components-shards

I have a signup component which has a form, and a handleFormSubmit. It calls an api to route to the server which runs a sequelize create. That all works, but once the row is inserted, I would like to redirect to a certain view.

Currently in the promise after the insert, I have a history.push("/dashboard"). However this is just appending to the browser url and not actually redirecting.

here is the signup component so you can see the form, and also the handleFormSubmit. I would simply like it to redirect to the "/dashboard" route:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import {
  Card,
  CardHeader,
  ListGroup,
  ListGroupItem,
  Row,
  Col,
  Form,
  FormGroup,
  FormInput,
  FormSelect,
  FormTextarea,
  Button
} from "shards-react";

// GET DATA FROM API (which calls routes from express server)
import API from "../../utils/API";
import Auth from "../../utils/Auth";
import { createHashHistory } from 'history'
export const history = createHashHistory();

class Signup extends Component {
  state = {
  };

  handleInputChange = event => {
    const { id, value } = event.target;
    this.setState({
      [id]: value
    });
  };

  handleFormSubmit = event => { 
    event.preventDefault();
    // console.log("Yo");
      API.addUser({

        firstName: this.state.feFirstName,
        lastName: this.state.feLastName,
        email: this.state.feEmail,
        password: this.state.fePassword,
        address1: this.state.feAddress,
        city: this.state.feCity,
        state: this.state.feInputState,
        zip: this.state.feZipCode,
        description: this.state.feDescription,
        userName: this.state.feEmail,
        imageLink: this.state.feImage,
        title: this.state.feTitle,
        github: this.state.feGithub,
        linkedin: this.state.feLinkedIn,
        phone: "",
        userRating: "1",
        bizRating: "1"

      })
        .then( res =>
          // console.log("Added,apparently");
          {
            // set the token and then redirect to the "/books" route
            // Auth.setToken(res.data.token);
            Auth.setToken(res.data.token);
            // console.log("TOKEN: " , res.data.token);
            console.log(res.data);
            history.push(`/dashboard/`);
          })
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
    // }
  }



  render() {
    return (

    <Card small className="mb-4">
      <CardHeader className="border-bottom">
        <h6 className="m-0">Personal Info</h6>
      </CardHeader>
      <ListGroup flush>
        <ListGroupItem className="p-3">
          <Row>
            <Col>
              <Form>
                <Row form>
                  {/* First Name */}
                  <Col md="6" className="form-group">
                    <label htmlFor="feFirstName">First Name</label>
                    <FormInput
                      id="feFirstName"
                      placeholder="First Name"
                    // value=""
                    onChange={this.handleInputChange}
                    />
                  </Col>
                  {/* Last Name */}
                  <Col md="6" className="form-group">
                    <label htmlFor="feLastName">Last Name</label>
                    <FormInput
                      id="feLastName"
                      placeholder="Last Name"
                    // value=""
                    onChange={this.handleInputChange}
                    />
                  </Col>
                </Row>
                <Row form>
                  {/* Email */}
                  <Col md="6" className="form-group">
                    <label htmlFor="feEmail">Email</label>
                    <FormInput
                      type="email"
                      id="feEmail"
                      placeholder="Email Address"
                    // value=""
                    onChange={this.handleInputChange}
                      autoComplete="email"
                    />
                  </Col>
                  {/* Password */}
                  <Col md="6" className="form-group">
                    <label htmlFor="fePassword">Password</label>
                    <FormInput
                      type="password"
                      id="fePassword"
                      placeholder="Password"
                    // value=""
                    onChange={this.handleInputChange}
                      autoComplete="current-password"
                    />
                  </Col>
                </Row>
                <FormGroup>
                  <label htmlFor="feAddress">Address</label>
                  <FormInput
                    id="feAddress"
                    placeholder="Address"
                    // value=""
                    onChange={this.handleInputChange}
                  />
                </FormGroup>
                <Row form>
                  {/* City */}
                  <Col md="6" className="form-group">
                    <label htmlFor="feCity">City</label>
                    <FormInput
                      id="feCity"
                      placeholder="City"
                    // value=""
                    onChange={this.handleInputChange}
                    />
                  </Col>
                  {/* State */}
                  <Col md="4" className="form-group">
                    <label htmlFor="feInputState">State</label>
                    <FormSelect id="feInputState">
                      <option>Choose...</option>
                      <option>...</option>
                    </FormSelect>
                  </Col>
                  {/* Zip Code */}
                  <Col md="2" className="form-group">
                    <label htmlFor="feZipCode">Zip</label>
                    <FormInput
                      id="feZipCode"
                      placeholder="Zip"
                    // value=""
                    onChange={this.handleInputChange}
                    />
                  </Col>
                </Row>
                <Row form>
                  {/* Title */}
                  <Col md="6" className="form-group">
                    <label htmlFor="feTitle">Title</label>
                    <FormInput
                      id="feTitle"
                      placeholder="Title"
                    // value=""
                    onChange={this.handleInputChange}
                    />
                  </Col>
                  {/* Image */}
                  <Col md="6" className="form-group">
                    <label htmlFor="feImage">Image</label>
                    <FormInput
                      id="feImage"
                      placeholder="Image"
                    // value=""
                    onChange={this.handleInputChange}
                    />
                  </Col>
                </Row>
                <Row form>
                  {/* Github */}
                  <Col md="6" className="form-group">
                    <label htmlFor="feGithub">Github</label>
                    <FormInput
                      id="feGithub"
                      placeholder="Github Profile"
                    // value=""
                    onChange={this.handleInputChange}
                    />
                  </Col>
                  {/* LinkedIn */}
                  <Col md="6" className="form-group">
                    <label htmlFor="feLinkedIn">LinkedIn</label>
                    <FormInput
                      id="feLinkedIn"
                      placeholder="LinkedIn Profile"
                    // value=""
                    onChange={this.handleInputChange}
                    />
                  </Col>
                </Row>
                <Row form>
                  {/* Description */}
                  <Col md="12" className="form-group">
                    <label htmlFor="feDescription">Description</label>
                    <FormTextarea id="feDescription" rows="5"
                      // value=""
                      onChange={this.handleInputChange} 
                      />
                  </Col>
                </Row>
                <Button onClick={this.handleFormSubmit} theme="accent">Add Account</Button>
              </Form>
            </Col>
          </Row>
        </ListGroupItem>
      </ListGroup>
    </Card>
  );
  }
}

export default Signup;
```

I also want to note that this is the shards dashboard template, so this is how the client app.js is set.

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from "react-router-dom";

import routes from "./routes";
import withTracker from "./withTracker";

import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import "./styles/shards-dashboards.1.1.0.min.css";

export default () => (
  <Router basename={process.env.REACT_APP_BASENAME || ""}>
    <div>
      {routes.map((route, index) => {
        return (
          <Route
            key={index}
            path={route.path}
            exact={route.exact}
            component={withTracker(props => {
              return (
                <route.layout {...props}>
                  <route.component {...props} />
                </route.layout>
              );
            })}
          />
        );
      })}
    </div>
  </Router>
);
```

And that being the case, it references my routes.js like this. so I do have routes set.

```
// CUSTOM ROUTES
import Home from "./views/Home";
import Portfolio from "./views/UserPortfolio";
import AddFolio from "./views/PortfolioAdd";
import AddProject from "./views/ProjectAdd";
import Signup from "./views/SignUp";
import Dashboard from "./views/Dashboard";

export default [
  {
    path: "/",
    exact: true,
    layout: DefaultLayout,
    component: () => <Redirect to="/home" />
  },
  {
    path: "/home",
    layout: DefaultLayout,
    component: Home
  },
  {
    path: "/folio",
    layout: DefaultLayout,
    component: Portfolio
  }, 
  {
    path: "/addfolio",
    layout: DefaultLayout,
    component: AddFolio
  },   
  {
    path: "/addproject",
    layout: DefaultLayout,
    component: AddProject
  },   

  // USER ROUTES
  {
    path: "/signup",
    layout: DefaultLayout,
    component: Signup
  }, 
  {
    path: "/dashboard",
    layout: DefaultLayout,
    component: Dashboard
  },
```

In the end I would simply like to see a redirect to ANY route in the promise, doesn't matter to me which one. Just so I see it working.

so please let me know what info needs to be provided, because i'm not sure how familiar everyone is with a shards implementation, as it is apparently sort of different from a standard react route setup. I'm sure I'm leaving out some info. Thanks all!

Comment: you have created an `hash` history. Doesn't the push does something like `#/dashboard` ?

Comment: you need to use `withRouter` to access the history object and not importing it directly. The official doc site could help you on `withRouter` since you are already using `BrowserRouter`

Comment: yes you are correct. I changed it to this: import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history'
export const history = createBrowserHistory();
and it now populates the url in the address bar properly. For example, locally once it submits, it does properly set the url to "http://localhost:3000/dashboard/" but it just never actually redirects.

Comment: To redirect you have to make use of `withRouter`. Read about it in the offical docs.

Answer (score 0):

Panther was correct, needed to wrap component in withRouter

so on the component, add this: import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
and then "export default withRouter(whateverClassName);" at the bottom